# TFS Build : the auto merge oprtion is not supported for the conflict on item

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

Whenever I run my build it fails with this error message:

"The auto merge oprtion is not supported for the conflict on item ManagementService.cs"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there is a source control conflict for the mentioned file. This typically occurs when two people edit the same file and TFS is unable to decide which change to keep. This is typically known as a merge conflict, because it happens when you try to merge (check in) your changes with what's currently stored on the server.

If it happens not when you try to check in your changes (which would be the common case), but rather as part of the build process, it could be due to files left over from previous builds. Make sure that your source code is built in an empty directory.

Failing all else, check out a fresh copy of the source code to a separate workspace and verify that your existing workspace has not somehow been corrupted. I can recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) for doing quick recursive directory comparisons.

Comment: Thank you.  I had this happen to me when I tried to use a changeset for a private tfs build whose files where not merged with the latest source code and eventually exposed a merge conflict.